# Accessing Javascript Object after Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript

I've been trying for sometime now to access this one object "baseURI":[image]

If you look at the image above, I'm trying to get "baseURI". 
In order to get what I have in the image, I do this:

```
var onDrop = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
}
```

But when I try to get the objects inside of MouseEvent, I get "undefined". Here's what I tried.

```
var onDrop = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.originalEvent.MouseEvent.srcElement.baseURI);
}
```

I also tried a bunch of other ways, what am I missing?

I made a fiddle if it helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/sta2M/1/

Comment: `MouseEvent` is its prototype, not a property. ( As in you dont need to do `.MouseEvent`

Comment: Holy Crap, I feel like an idiot.

Comment: I spent 62 minutes smashing my head against a desk trying to figure out why I couldn't grab it. Please Post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseEvent` is its prototype, not a property. You can ommit `.MouseEvent`.